# Is there a full HTML/Javascript online search engine?

Tags: javascript, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm looking for a search engine that would also index the html and javascript code, and not only the rendering.

Use case: Some specific hardcoded javascript parameter is used somewhere in the ~80000 pages site I work on. I need to find where is the page with a specific parameter.

Much appreciated.

EDIT: Context: I don't have direct access to the code. The parameter in question is used to configure some info to send to Adobe's Omniture (into which I get weird hits).

EDIT: Maybe there is no such search engine. I'll keep the question open...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `grep` can do this :)

Comment: @Spiny I don't have direct access to the code of the site. Or even a svn of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid so. You *could* download it first using HTTrack or something (http://www.httrack.com/), and then search through it. But I don't know how long that would take.

Comment: @Shawn I'm in the team that writes specifications for the implementation of the tracking code. Basically we provide snippets of JS, but they are not always followed to the letter. The weird hits we have can come from any of the ~300 projects we did last year.

Comment: @Spiny HTTrack could help, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Do you have, or can you set up, detailed logs for your tracker requests? You could then parse the logs for weird hits and inspect the referrer url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an online search engine that would do that. The closest you can get to that would be [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) which indexes public source code. You might be able to make use of it if you host your code as a public repository on services such as [github](http://github.com), [google code](http://code.google.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), etc.

If it is a private project you're working on, then you should have access to the source code, no? If so, then as @Spiny Norman mentioned, you can simply use `grep`.

For a large source base, you might be better off using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

If you have your code in SVN/Git, look up [svnquery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/) or [git grep](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html).

Comment: Google Code Search code yielded no result. 
Also, I don't have direct access to the code.